# Laravel Blade not pushing to stack when view rendered in function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**The problem**

When rendering a view with blade, I call a function which generate a form (with the [Laravel Form Builder](http://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/overview/quick-start.html)). This all works like a charm! For my project I need a custom form and a custom form field. After some puzzeling also a success, still no problem huray! Now I need a way to push a link to a list in my parent view.

*parentview.blade.php*

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul class="wizard_steps">
    @stack('category_steps')
  </ul>
  {!! form($form) !!}
</div>
```

*customForm.blade.php*

```
@push('category_steps')
<li>
  <a href="#{{$options['real_name']}}">
    <span class="step_no"></span>
    <span class="step_descr">
      <?php if ($showLabel && $options['label'] !== false && $options['label_show']): ?>
        {{ $options['label'] }}
      <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
@endpush

<div id="#{{$options['real_name']}}">
  {!! form_rest($options['field_form']) !!}
</div>
```

And here is the problem. The list item is not added to the stack in the parent.

**Steps to reproduce**

I've narrowed the problem down to `{!! form($form) !!}` that. So to reproduce:

- make a file `home.blade.php` and paste text:

*home.blade.php*

```
<?php
/** @return string */
function test()
{
    return view('test')->render();
}
?>
@stack('moreTest')
{!! test() !!}
```

- now the file `test.blade.php` and paste text:

*test.blade.php*

```
@push('moreTest')
  <p>This is not pushed</p>
@endpush
```

Anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

P.S.:Working with laravel 5.4.23

Comment: Try throwing an @parent directive directly below @push('moreTest')

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work